# Proof of double Doppler shift

Tags: optics, reflection, doppler-effect, redshift

We know that the Doppler effect for EM radiation is $\Delta$$f$ = $\frac{v}{c}$$f_0$

$\Delta$$f$ = the change in frequency

v = the relative speed of the source and observer

c = the speed of light in a vacuum

$f_0$ = the original frequency

I have been told simply the change in frequency, $\Delta$$f$, of an EM wave is doubled when the source sends a wave to a moving observer and then it reflects off a moving observer and it gets received by the source.[image: Diagram]

But I don't understand why this happens. I tried multiple times to use the above equation to prove the total $\Delta$$f$ is twice of that of the first wave. But every time I fail. So I would like to see a mathematical proof rather than word explanations. Thank you!

Comment: Consider the motion of the “image” of the source produced by the reflection of the waves, originating from the source, from the observer.

Comment: First consider someone sitting on the mirror and ask yourself what frequency the oncoming wave has for them. After reflection it has that same frequency relative to them. After that, consider that wave as it approaches you.

Comment: What do you mean by "total Δf is twice of that of the first wave"? The first wave can't have a change in frequency, it just has whatever frequency it has.

Comment: @g-s I meant why is the total (back and forth) Δf twice of the Δf of the first wave travelling from the source to the observer due to Doppler's effect?

Comment: @QuantumYitian Okay, now I get it. You're shifting frames. The first frequency shift is the difference between the frequency measured by an observer at velocity $v$ before the reflection and an observer at velocity $0$ before the reflection. The second frequency shift is the difference between the frequency measured by an observer at velocity $0$ after the reflection and the frequency measured by an observer at velocity $0$ before the reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formula for the Doppler shift is $$f_r=f_e\sqrt{\frac{c+v}{c-v}}$$ where $f_r$ is the received frequency and $f_e$ is the emitted frequency. Now, for small velocities we can perform a first-order Taylor series expansion in $v$ and write $$f_r\approx f_e \left( 1+\frac{v}{c} \right)$$ but remember that this is an approximation.

In this case a reflection counts as a reception followed by an immediate emission at the same frequency. So there are two Doppler shifts, one for the shift of the received frequency and the other for the shift of the emitted frequency. So then we have two Doppler shifts $$f_r = f_e\sqrt{\frac{c+v}{c-v}}\sqrt{\frac{c+v}{c-v}} \approx f_e \left(1+\frac{2v}{c} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I get it, so fr = $(1+/)^2$ and when you expand $(1+/)^2$, $v^2$/$c^2$ is approximated as 0 right?

Comment: @QuantumYitian yes the approximation is a first order Taylor series expansion. So all terms second order and higher (in $v$) are dropped

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of the answers by @Dale and @JEB using the Bondi $k$-calculus.

Using a variant of my diagram from
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/relativity-using-bondi-k-calculus/
to handle two *approaching* astronauts, we draw

[image: robphy-BondiK]

$k$ (the Bondi-$k$-factor) is introduced as a proportionality constant that depends only on the relative-velocity (and not on the period $T$). By radar measurement definitions,
we get $k=\sqrt{\displaystyle \frac{c\Delta t+\Delta x}{c\Delta t- \Delta x}}=\sqrt{\displaystyle \frac{c+v}{c-v}}$, the formula for the Doppler factor.

We have
\begin{align*}
\Delta f
&=f_r -f_e\\
&=\frac{k^2}{T}-\frac{1}{T}\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left( \frac{c+v}{c-v} \right)}{T}-\frac{1}{T}\\
&=\left( \displaystyle\left( \frac{c+v}{c-v} \right)-1\right)\frac{1}{T}\\
&= \displaystyle\left( \frac{2v}{c-v} \right)f_e\\
\end{align*}
For $v\ll c$, we have $\Delta f\approx \displaystyle\frac{2v}{c}f_e$.

To connect with @Dale's answer,
write instead
\begin{align*}
f_r 
&= \frac{k^2}{T}\\
&= k^2 f_e
\end{align*}
in agreement with @Dale.

Answer (score 0):

The double Doppler shift can be derived kinematically: the 4-acceleration ($a^{\mu}$) imparted by the light must be orthogonal to mirror's 4-velocity ($v_{\mu}$). (This is required to keep the mirror "on-shell").

The initial  photon has 4-momentum:

$$ p_{\mu} = (p, 0, 0, p) $$

The reflected photon has 4-momentum:

$$ p'_{\mu} = (p', 0, 0, -p') $$

So the momentum transfer, which is proportional to $a_{\mu}$, is:

$$ q_{\mu} = p'_{\mu} -p_{\mu}=(p'-p,0,0, -p'-p) $$

Meanwhile, the mirror moving away along the $z$-axis has 4-velocity:

$$ v^{\mu} = \gamma(c, 0, 0, v) $$

The condition is then:

$$q_{\mu}v^{\mu} = \gamma\big((p'-p)c - (p'+p)v\big)= 0$$

so that:

$$(p-p')c = (p+p')v$$

Subbing in  $ pc = E= hf $:

$$ f' = f \frac{c-v}{c+v} $$

which agrees with the checked answer.