# Misunderstanding of Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Let be the following two transformations :
\begin{cases}x'_{1}=\gamma(x-vt)\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)\\x'_{2}=\gamma(x+vt)\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)\end{cases}
$\gamma$ Lorentz factor.

Multiply (1) by (2): $$x'_{1}x'_{2}=\gamma^{2}[x^{2}-(vt)^{2}]$$
for the light : $$x'_{1}x'_{2}=\gamma^{2}[x^{2}-(\beta x)^{2}]=x^{2}$$
It is as we have identical transformations:\begin{cases}x=\gamma(x-vt)\\x=\gamma(x+vt)\end{cases}
where is the error ?

Comment: Those seem like two distinct Lorenz boosts to opposite directions. It seems to lack also the transformations of time coordinates (considering 2D $t-x$ spacetime). I also don't get why you labeled two distinct boosts $(t,x) \to (t'_1, x'_1)$ and $(t,x) \to (t'_2, x'_2)$ and then later (in the end) dropped the labels... I believe doing it keeping track of time coordinate and of correct labels will dissipate any confusion

Comment: The two other transformations can be deduced from the two first ones, I have x'(1)x'(2)=x², I have simplified by x'(1)=x and x'(2)=x !

Comment: Why should $v=\beta \frac{x}{t}$ ? Remember $\beta =v/c$.

Comment: What does "for the light" mean?

Comment: @OP, That's the point, it doesn't really make sense to make that simplification. Let's center our analysis on the "pre-boosted" reference frame. It measures distances using $x$ (it also keeps track o time using $t$). After boosting, it measures distances using $x'$ and time using $t'$. $x'$ and $x$ will in general be distinct at arbitrary times $t$ and $t'$. If those frames "instantaneously coincide", so to speak, then that fact should be accounted for on each time coordinate as well...

Comment: Frederic and Thomas, In the LTs x'=Ɣ (x-vt) =Ɣ(x-vx/c ), x'/c=t'=Ɣ(t-vx/c²), I replaced t by t= x/c , the distance (x) is traveled by a ray of light , which gives the transformation for time.

Answer (score 5):

You assume that $(vt)^2=(βx)^2$, which is equivalent to $x=\pm ct$, so I guess you are Lorentz transforming the worldline of a light beam that passes through the origin, and that's what "for the light" means.

It's true that $x_1'x_2'=x^2$ as you derived, but it doesn't follow that $x=x_1'$ and $x=x_2'$. It just means that $x$ is the geometric mean of $x_1'$ and $x_2'$.

In fact $x_{1,2}' = \displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1\pm β}{1\mp β}}\,x$ (with the sign depending on the sign in $x=\pm ct$). $\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1+β}{1-β}}$ is the Doppler shift factor, so the relationship you found is a consequence of the reciprocity of Doppler shifts.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, what I missed .